# $in operator performance in MongodDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Is it slow to use the `$in` operator in MongoDB with a large array of data (more than 5 millions entries)?

```
posts.find({
    id: {
        $in : ['id1','id2'] 
    }
})
```

In Java:

```
Page<PostsEntity> postsEntities = postsRepository.findByIdIn(ids, new PageRequest(i, PAGE_SIZE));
```

My `id` is a String and it is indexed, but the query takes way too much time.

Are `$in` queries not recommended for large-sized datasets?

Comment: 5kk strings is a lot. Is `id` indexed? Profile it https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/ to confirm how much of "way too much"  is spent on DB side.

Comment: What is large here? Your number of stored documents? Or the items in the `$in` parameter ('id1', 'id2' in your example)? Also, are you querying the "_id" field or something else? Lastly, is it really strings you are dealing with here or ObjectIds?

Comment: which version of mongo are you using. I don't think `$in` uses index(even if you have one)

Comment: id is a String and is indexed. I only have two items in the `$in` parameter. I use mongo 3.6.0.

Comment: ah, fair enough. I confused it with 5kk strings in the query array. With 2 items in `$in` it should be pretty quick then. What profiler says?

Comment: Try running this and see if your index gets used: `posts.find({
    id: {
        $in : ['id1','id2'] 
    }
}).explain()`

Comment: @dnickless: The index is not used... Thanks for the hint :) I'm gonna fix this, it should be quicker after that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by putting an index for ids :)